# How to set value of model field as currently logged user? Django

Tags: django, default-value

I have Event model which has a field creator as ForeignKey with attribute User. In views.py, I have create_event which creates event using `EventForm`. How to set default value of creator in `EventForm` as currently logged user? It is set default as admin, I do not want to set it manually every time I create an event, because it would be annoying if I have a lot of users created.

**models.py:**

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    SPORT = (
        ('Football', 'Football'),
        ('Volleyball', 'Volleyball'),
        ('Basketball', 'Basketball'),
        ('Futsal', 'Futsal'),
        ('Tennis', 'Tennis'),
        ('Handball', 'Handball'),
        ('Ice Hockey', 'Ice Hockey'),
        ('Paintball', 'Paintball')
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=SPORT)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    end_event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=date.today())
    current_members = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total_members = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0, max_length=5)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

**views.py:**

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_event(request):
    form = EventForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'events/create_event.html', context)
```

**forms.py:**

```py
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['creator', 'sport', 'event_name', 'event_date', 'end_event_date', 'total_members', 'current_members', 'event_location', 'cost', 'description']
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you expect here. To save `creator` as currently logged in user you can do: `form.save(commited=False)`, then set the `creator` as current user `form.creator = request.user` and finally save the form `form.save()`. But, "It is set default as admin" means that you logged in as admin, so then what you expect in "currently logged user"?

Comment: You are right, now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the **`creator`** field from the model form

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = [
            "creator", # remove this field
            "sport",
            "event_name",
            "event_date",
            "end_event_date",
            "total_members",
            "current_members",
            "event_location",
            "cost",
            "description",
        ]
```

Then use **`commit`** parameter of [`Form.save(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) as

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_event(request):
    form = EventForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            event.creator = request.user
            event.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'events/create_event.html', context)
```

Comment: If user logged in as admin, it's still set the `creator` as admin user, where OP said this "It is set default as admin, I do not want to set it manually every time I create an even".

Comment: @Charnel *"How to set default value of creator in EventForm as currently logged user?"*?

Comment: Yep, title and details description asking for controversial things.